# Extending with a base controller and calling parent::WhateverAction

Tags: zend-framework

I'm working on a Zend 1.* project where every controller extends a base controller and we duplicate actions in both with the child calling "parent::whateverAction()".

Is duplicating/calling a parent action inside a controller common practice in Zend? I always assumed such techniques warranted a quick flogging. Is it my misunderstanding?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the app. Controller plugins or action helpers are a better solution to many of the things you see people creating base controllers for, but there are some situations where a base controller can be useful. E.g. I had one application where several controllers had very similar CRUD operations, so it made things easier to have a "crud controller" which implemented these things in a standard way, and the individual controllers could override individual methods if they needed to do one of the operations slightly differently.

Answer (score 0):

Any common processing that you anticipate placing into a `BaseController` could in go into:

1. `BaseController::xxxAction()` as a public method, as you seem to describe.
2. `BaseController::xxxMethod()` as a protected method
3. In a custom [action-helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html)

Typically, I would not create public `xxxAction()` in the base. To my mind, an *action* should be invoked directly when a route is mapped to it. Actions stashed up in a base controller class don't really satisfy that criterion.

Dumping that common processing into a protected method `xxxAction()` on the `BaseController` is pretty common and probably fine. All child controllers will have access to that processing and can call upon it in their actions.

The only real downside to that approach is that it tends to bloat the `BaseController`. After all, not all actions will use that particular functionality stashed up in the base, so why load it and parse it on a request if it's not going to be used on that request?

For this reason, the "Zendish" way is to create an action-helper to contain that common functionality. There are two primary benefits to this approach:

1. The helper can be invoked in an action and it is loaded *on the fly*. No need to parse and load that code during requests that don't call upon it.
2. In principle, since the helper is its own class, it can be more easily unit-tested.

Not exactly a hard answer; just a braindump of some thoughts.